# I need to group_by then dplyr::filter a data frame to keep multiple rows based on min and max

Tags: r, dataframe, filter, group-by, slice

```
data1 <- data.frame(PIT = c(20111002, 20111002, 20111002, 20111002, 20111003, 20111003, 20111003, 20111003, 20111003, 20111003, 20111003, 20111003, 20111003, 20111003, 20111003, 20111003,  20111006, 20111006, 20111006, 20111006, 20111006) , rx = c(39,  42, 101, 109,  39,  42, 101, 109, 138, 138, 138, 136, 138, 138, 139, 139, 39, 39, 39, 39 , 42))

data2 <- data.frame(PIT = c(2011102, 2011102, 20111003, 20111003, 20111006, 20111006), rx = c(39, 109, 39, 138, 39, 42))
```

I need to create `data2` from `data1`. Basically, two values for each `PIT`: 1) the first minimum value of `rx` and 2) either the first maximum value of `rx` OR the first value of `rx` > 110.

I don't think I'm explaining this well, but am at a loss for words and patience, having tried all sorts of combinations of which, match, first, slice, min, max, filter, and you name it, I've tried it (except obviously for the solution). Also, yes, I did group_by and tried if_else.

I have tried too many possible solutions to include here. Actually, I just spent fifteen minutes trying to post code into this message, but can't seem to format it correctly?

Comment: "either the first maximum value of rx OR the first value of rx > 110" <- how do you decide which one?

Comment: I'm not sure how best to explain. Sometimes when grouped by PIT, max(rx) is less than c(136, 138, 139), so I need that row. Sometimes, max(rx) is one of c(136, 138, 139), in which case I need the first row containing the max. In fact, I always need the first row and only the first row containing either the min or max. It might make sense if I explain rx is a receiver location along a river and I'm looking for the furthest south (min(rx)) and furthest north (max(rx)), but 136, 138, 139 are all the same zone, so I need the first row containing one of those. Sorry, words are failing me.

Comment: maybe you could build out a better sample input, and desired output, if words are escaping you

Comment: I say this because you never before mentioned the c(136, 138, 139 thing

Comment: it seems like there are four cases: one where rx is lower than 136, one where it's higher than 139, one where it's in c(136, 138, 139), and one where it's the missing number 137. Outline what you want in all of those cases

Answer (score 1):

A one-liner:

```
dplyr::filter(data1, rx %in% c(min(rx), max(rx)) | rx >= 110, .by = PIT)
```

Unsure how you were wanting "either the first maximum value of rx OR the first value of rx > 110" to work...but this gets the correct answer.

Comment: Typo. Change to `data1` (+1).

Comment: Thank you. This seems to almost work, but I'm getting multiple rows for each PIT and I need just two rows, the first min and first max (or first row containing either 136, 138, 139). How do I take the first? I've tried first(), match(), head(), but they don't work.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this works. It might not be the best or most streamlined, but it works.

```
min <- data1 %>% 
  group_by(PIT) %>%
  dplyr::filter(rx==min(rx)) %>%
  slice(1)

max1 <- data1 %>% 
  group_by(PIT) %>%
  dplyr::filter(max(rx)<110 & rx == max(rx)) %>%
  slice(1)

max2 <- data1 %>% 
  group_by(PIT) %>%
  dplyr::filter(rx > 110) %>%
  slice(1)

data2 <- dplyr::full_join(min, max1) %>%
  dplyr::full_join(max2) %>% arrange(PIT,Presence)
```